# How can I show that P is a probability measure on (\omega,sigma(X)) and how do i find the distribution of X?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

I have already done problem 1, problem 2 references #1.
I need help showing that P is a probability measure and how to find its distribution

Answer (score 0):

Look up the [definition of probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure#Definition) and check that $P$ satisfies it.

For the distribution of $X$, it suffices to write down what $P(X=1)$ and $P(X=2)$ equal.

Comment: is P(X=1)=1/7? and P(X=2)=1?